# Converting data set from one form to another

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I wish to convert Data to Data2. Both sets are provided below. Note that the second set has an arbitrary parameter "t". How can this be done.

```
Data = {{{2013, 1, 1}, 49.90611}, {{2013, 1, 2}, 
   50.33952}, {{2013, 1, 3}, 50.75688}, {{2013, 1, 4}, 
   50.7649}, {{2013, 1, 7}, 50.24321}, {{2013, 1, 8}, 49.256}, 
     {{2013, 1, 9}, 49.28008}, {{2013, 1, 10}, 
   49.44863}, {{2013, 1, 11}, 49.26403}, {{2013, 1, 14}, 
   49.46468}, {{2013, 1, 15}, 49.56099}, {{2013, 1, 16}, 49.9944}}



Data2 = {{t, 49.90611}, {t + 1, 50.33952}, {t + 2, 50.75688}, {t + 3, 
   50.7649}, {t + 4, 50.24321}, {t + 5, 49.256}, {t + 6, 
   49.28008}, {t + 7, 49.44863}, {t + 8, 49.26403}, 
     {t + 9, 49.46468}, {t + 10, 49.56099}, {t + 11, 49.9944}}
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Data2=MapThread[{t + #1, Last@#2} &, {Range[0, Length@Data - 1], Data}]
```

> {{t, 49.9061}, {1 + t, 50.3395}, {2 + t, 50.7569}, {3 + t, 
>     50.7649}, {4 + t, 50.2432}, {5 + t, 49.256}, {6 + t, 
>     49.2801}, {7 + t, 49.4486}, {8 + t, 49.264}, {9 + t, 
>     49.4647}, {10 + t, 49.561}, {11 + t, 49.9944}}

Answer (score 3):

Works if dates aren't sequential days:

```
Data2 = Thread[{t + QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[Data[[1, 1]], #] & /@ Data[[All, 1]], Data[[All, 2]]}]
```

(Not sure if that's what you were going for, if not...)

```
Data2 = Thread[{t + Range[0, Length@Data - 1], Data[[All, 2]]}]
```

Comment: @kala  Yes, these inputs are good alternatives, flexible.

Comment: @thils Note that the first option calculates number of DAYS from first data point and adds `t`. Again, not sure if that's what you were after, but coupled with @image_doctor's answer, you have a couple good choices.